# automate testcomplete with cruiseControl.net

Tags: testing, cruisecontrol.net, testcomplete

I am using testComplete software for doing end-to-end test.

Do you know if there is a way to launch tests and get results from cruise control .net?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of CruiseControl.net is to execute a task (process) and include its result (transformed or raw) in the build log. The dashboard, or other tool, can then review the build log and present the results of the tests (in your case) as you need.

In this vein, you should just execute `testexecute` as required to produce the results file. You can then use the `merge` task in the `publishers` section to include the results.

There are many dashboard transformers (typically XSL transforms) which allow rendering/display of certain parts of the build log, e.g. the msbuild or nunit test-results.

The below could be an example

```
<project>
 ...
 <tasks>
  <exec>
   <executable>testexecute.exe</executable>
   <buildArgs>... /out:results.xml ...</buildArgs>
  </exec>
 </tasks>
 <publishers>
  <merge>
   <files>
    <file>results.xml</file>
   </files>
  </merge>
 </publishers>
</project>
```

See the ability to configure the dashboard here: [configuring the dashboard](http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Configuring_the_Dashboard_(dashboardconfig))

Answer (score 0):

We do this. We use Nant to run testexecute. We then parse the resulting xml log file from testexecute which has the test results in it. We determine pass or fail for each test and write this to a simple line by line file with testname | pass/fail. Then we put these results into a database to view on our tests dashboard. We run the tests on some kind of schedule. That's up to you.

On our tests viewing website we link to the mht file for that particular run of test execute so you can drill down more.

The hardest part might have been getting the tests to run properly on a headless test machine. That took a lot of tinkering around to get right.